# emacs-daemon startup freezes if file has auto-save data

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I set up *desktop.el* so that emacs automatically reopens all files on startup that were left open last time I killed emacs.

Now when I start emacs as a daemon and one of the reopened files has auto-save-data, the daemon displays the usual auto-save-data-message `("...file has auto save data...")` and **waits for confirmation** - but does not continue the initialization. Without confirmation the daemon will stay in this state and new connections (eg via `emacsclient -c`) are accepted but not processed.

Is there a way to disable confirmations during the daemons startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit: Updated to match Zarza's working version:

```
(defadvice desktop-restore-file-buffer
  (around my-desktop-restore-file-buffer-advice)
  "Be non-interactive while starting a daemon."
  (if (and (daemonp)
           (not server-process))
      (let ((noninteractive t))
        ad-do-it)
    ad-do-it))
(ad-activate 'desktop-restore-file-buffer)
```

`(command-line)` starts the server process, but only "after loading the user's init file and after processing all command line arguments".

Comment: Thank you Phils, that helped me a lot! I had to change the advice target to make it work, because the suggested function `desktop-read` is wrapped with `(unless noninteractive...`. I changed it to `desktop-restore-file-buffer`:

`(defadvice desktop-restore-file-buffer (around my-desktop-restore-file-buffer-advice)
  (if (and (daemonp)
           (not server-process))
      (let ((noninteractive t))
        ad-do-it)
    ad-do-it)
   )
(ad-activate 'desktop-restore-file-buffer)`