# How can I prevent emacs hanging when initial-buffer-choice has auto save data?

Tags: emacs, advising-functions

I use emacs in daemon mode and I also have an `initial-buffer-choice`
variable set.  Sometimes emacs will crash when I am editing the file
that I use for `initial-buffer-choice`.  In this case, when I start
emacs with --daemon, it will hang with the message:

```
"todo.org has auto save data; consider M-x recover-this-file"
```

Since I mostly start the daemon from an init script, I can't confirm or
deny this dialog, so the daemon hangs forever.  How can I bypass the
notification of auto-save data in this case?  I don't mind losing the
auto save data if necessary.

Here was my attempt to do it:

```
(defadvice command-line
  (around my-command-line-advice)
  "Be non-interactive while starting a daemon."
  (if (and (daemonp)
           (not server-process))
      (let ((noninteractive t))
        ad-do-it)
    ad-do-it))
 (ad-activate 'command-line)
```

However, this doesn't work.  I still get the same hanging behaviour.
Indeed, putting a 'message' call inside the advice shows that the advice
isn't invoked at all.

Similar question: [emacs-daemon startup freezes if file has auto-save data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933134/).  However this solution does not work for `initial-buffer-choice`.  The accepted answer seems to have been edited from a previous version which may have successfully defined advice on `command-line` as I attempted to do, but unfortunately this version is now gone and replaced with a desktop.el-specific version.

Comment: `"... has auto save data; consider ..."` is just a message, not a dialog. The reason why the daemon hangs must be something else.

Comment: Perhaps taking a look at `after-find-file` within `files.el` might give you some ideas on how to resolve the confirmation issue.  Alternatively, take a look at the function that calls `after-find-file` when loading Emacs with `--daemon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the description of the behavior reported by the original poster in the question to this thread, it would appear that when Emacs is activated with `--daemon`, the `initial-buffer-choice` (i.e., to `find-file-noselect "~/.../todo.org"` [see `... lisp/startup.el`]) is being activated in the start-up sequence *before* the default setting of auto-save can be disabled with `(setq auto-save-default nil)`. Provided that changing the order has no effect [i.e., placing `(setq auto-save-default nil)` higher up *in priority* in the initialization file so that it precedes the `initial-buffer-choice`], then the next step is to take affirmative action to ensure that auto-save is disabled before opening a file (e.g., `todo.org`).  This can be achieved by placing `(setq initial-buffer-choice t)` and `(setq auto-save-default nil)` in the `init.el` or `.emacs` file (without a hook) -- then, to ensure that all other settings have been loaded first, use the `emacs-startup-hook` to `(kill-buffer "*scratch*")` and `(find-file "~/.../todo.org")` -- this ensures that auto-save is disabled *before* `find-file` is called (which uses `find-file-noselect` [see `... lisp/files.el`]).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to put this in your .emacs:

```
(setq auto-save-default nil)
```

Another (probably better solution) is to suppress the warning message by using this to find files instead:

```
(find-file-noselect FILENAME &optional NOWARN RAWFILE WILDCARDS)
```

As you can see here, you can suppress the warning message using the optional NOWARN argument (because that is what is causing the problem).

Source: [this EmacsWiki page](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoSave#toc6)

Here is a change you could make if I were to solve this for myself.
Define in the .emacs setup:

```
(defun find-file (filename &optional wildcards)
  (interactive
   (find-file-read-args "Find file: "
                        (confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer)))

  ; the "t" here is normally set to "nil", this should solve the problem
  (let ((value (find-file-noselect filename t nil wildcards)))  
    (if (listp value)
    (mapcar 'switch-to-buffer (nreverse value))
      (switch-to-buffer value))))
```

EDIT: This did not help anyone so far, but for completeness it might help out some.

The current way confirmed by the questioner is to use the `emacs-startup-hook` and combine it with `(kill-buffer "*scratch*")` and `(find-file "~/.../todo.org")`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dualinity.  Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce the original issue at the moment.  I will test and accept the answer when I can reproduce it.

Comment: That didn't help. `emacs --daemon` still hangs while loading

Comment: Perhaps the `initial-buffer-choice` is being activated in the start-up sequence *before* `(setq auto-save-default nil)`.  If changing the order has no effect, then consider using `(setq initial-buffer-choice t)` in addition to `(setq auto-save-default nil)`, and then use the `emacs-startup-hook` to `(kill-buffer "*scratch*")` `(find-file "~/.../todo.org")`.

Comment: This final one worked -- using `emacs-startup-hook`, although it's a horrible hack, if you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Since "*...has auto save data; consider M-x recover-this-file*" is only a message I am not sure that the problem is really related to the auto-save file. But, if this is the case you could built a test whether the auto-save directory for emacs is empty (`directory-files`) into your server init file. If the auto-save directory is not empty, move all the files to another place and go on (`rename-file`).

I am really curious whether this would solve the problem.

**The real question is: How to debug server problems in emacs. Debug and edebug are pretty sensless in servermode. One should better trace everything to a file (something like logging).**

Comment: Yes, this solution worked, super hacky: `(let ((autosave-path "/home/amoe/etc/autosave")) (dolist (autosave-file (directory-files autosave-path nil "^#")) (rename-file (concat autosave-path "/" autosave-file) (concat "/tmp/" autosave-file))))`